# How can we use clickAt() command instead of click()?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, appium

In my application, I am able to find the coordinates where i need to click.

I dont see anywhere to perform clickAt cmd in eclipse(it is not listing that cmd in proposal) Why in Eclipse it is not available? Is there any library need to be added? I was using Actions class and doing mouse over and click, build, perform, still I am not able to click.

```
WebElement tElement = driver.findElement
(By.xpath("//*[@id='ext-component-4']"));
Actions action=new Actions(driver);
action.moveToElement(tElement).moveByOffset(650,300);
Thread.sleep(10000);
action.build().perform();
Actions vActions = new Actions(driver);
//vActions.moveToElement(Image);
vActions.doubleClick(Image);
Action vClickAction = vActions.build();
vClickAction.perform();
```

I believe I need to use only clickAt() cmd.

Please someone Help.

Comment: mouse over in Android Application ?? What kind of application you are automating ?

Answer (score 1):

There is no method in Action/s class such as ClickAt(). REF [javadoc](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/Actions.html).
Use `click(WebElement onElement)` 
Clicks in the middle of the given element.

OR use mobile specific commands such as tap

```
public class TouchAction
```

and method public `TouchAction tap(org.openqa.selenium.WebElement el)`

Tap the center of an element.

Comment: Yeah ! Agree with @abhijeet . I too checked for such method but there isn't.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use it with another way :

```
moveToElement(WebElement toElement, int xOffset, int yOffset)
```

Moves the mouse to an offset from the top-left corner of the element.
The code (Java) would look like this:

```
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);   
builder.moveToElement(elt, 10, 25).click().build().perform();
```